# Don't show the "new privilege" notification on signup

Tags: feature-request, privileges, notification-bar

On signup, users who have other accounts with enough reputation are greeted with three notifications.

[image: screenshot]

The third one seems pointless. Gaining a privilege from the association bonus isn't really an accomplishment. Also, since users have to have an account with higher reputation to get the bonus they will already be used to having those privileges, especially if they've associated accounts before.